# SD card not recognized by Acer A500

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, external-sd, acer-iconia-a500

I just bought a used Acer A500 16 GB tablet yesterday. Everything works great — except it doesn't recognize my 16 GB microSD card for storage, but says there is no external SD storage or it is emulated.

I don't know a lot about rooting and such; the guy just told me it was rooted and is running JellyBean 4.1, which works great.

Does anyone know how to get my SD card recognized again?

Comment: @Izzy Make sure to get the title when you edit ;)

Comment: Oh... I didn't figure anything wrong with it -- but true, now it's much clearer. I will watch out better next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensue that the device supports SDHC microSD cards.

Also ensure that the sd card is fat16 formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Try, running scandisk on your card after connecting it with your computer...it should work